# Why do I have some "encrypted" files on my Win7 Pro drive

Tags: windows, backup, encryption

For reasons I can't fathom I appear to have a lot of files on my drive that are considered as encrypted (I just tried to `xcopy /s /c /y /d a_dropbox_folder\*.* \\somewhere_on_my_nas_drive\` and got thousands of errors that the destination does not support encryption). I'm not convinced these files are encrypted - if they are decryption is transparent.

I'm a programmer and the area I'm backing up is my working project folders. Encrypted files included source code, generated DLL's , text files, zip files, data files generated by GIT and ReSharper...

The other clue is that all of this is in a folder managed by dropbox (although there may be similar issues outside of the DB folder - its the DB I'm trying to backup). I've added the /G option to xcopy and are re-running the backup, but I'd love to know whats going on.

Comment: What filesystem is your NAS drive using?

Comment: I'm not at home to check that right now, but why is it relevant? I'm trying to understand how the source PC ended up with files marked as encrypted, not why the destination won't accept them. How do I tell if a file is encrypted anyway?

Comment: It may well be a default error due to being unable to write for some reason or another; i'm thinking along the lines of problems i had with Netgear SC101's a few years ago where they used a different filesystem so the data from the hard drives was non-readable/recoverable when plugged into a standard PC...

Comment: No, adding a /G option to xcopy backs them up OK. It really is that windows thinks they are encrypted. But Win7 Pro doesn't support file system encryption (i.e. bitlocker) so what is making these encrypted (or marked as encrypted). They are not green in Explorer.